# What's the difference between iterating over FindItemsResults and FindItemsResults.Items?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

According to the documentation on MSDN, the [FindItemsResults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd635381(v=exchg.80).aspx) implements IEnumerable. It has a property called [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd636274(v=exchg.80).aspx) which implements ICollection. I can't find anywhere in the documentation whether the items in the collection are the same items that you would see when iterating over the `FindItemsResults` object, though. Are these items the same?

If they are, why does `FindItemsResults` even have the `Items` property? Why not just implement ICollection and not bother with the property?

Comment: I assume that iterating over the base object doesn't materialise the results immediately but calling `.Items` gives you a collection with everything in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is common to have the [Items] property as an array or collection and then allow a simple way to access them using IEnumerable for EF queries.

[FindItemsResults members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd635437(v=exchg.80).aspx) Does say that Items is the result.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something. Why bother with the `Items` property? Why not just implement `ICollection`?

Comment: IEnumerable is a fixed size.  So by default you can't add or remove items.  You can only iterate and query.  ICollection does not have those restrictions.  You would not want to Modify a search result set so IEnumerable is the best default.  And since it is assumed you would iterate the result sets it is perfect for this use.